# What do I use to run a user-transparent query on a search engine?

Tags: android, search, transparent

I want to do perform an internet search (think google images) on user input and display the first pic that comes back (in an imageview).

Do I use Webkit to do the search query?

I found ways to open the android google search application through an Intent, but that's not what I want to do.  I just want to do the query, and bring the results back in an array or something.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AsyncTask to perform the search in background and to populate the result in onPostExecute method. Take a look here http://code.google.com/p/google-search-java-sdk/ or use some other library to use google engine and perform the desired search queries.